# Can you tell me which LEGO set number this is?

Tags: set-identification

I bought this Lego set off the internet and I can’t figure out the set number.  Can someone tell me the set number?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I see some elements without LEGO logo on top of the studs, so it not entirely a LEGO set.

Answer (score 12):

As @mindstormsboi pointed out, it's a modification of [60009-1 Helicopter Arrest](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60009-1)

According to BrickLink, the only sets with both those [RBrown stairs](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30134&colorID=88&in=A) and the [100 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpx7&in=S) are:

- 10218-1 Pet Shop
- 10232-1 Palace Cinema
- 10246-1 Detective's Office
- 10255-1 Assembly Square
- 10264-1 Corner Garage
- 41108-1 Heartlake Food Market
- 60009-1 Helicopter Arrest
- 60069-1 Swamp Police Station
- 60130-1 Prison Island

and that doesn't look **exactly** like any of them. But if you remove 60009's  vehicles and pier and add a few bits, it's a good match.

I won't say **never**, but Lego doesn't often (that I know of) sell sets with treasure chests where the lid doesn't match the base. But @Zhaph - Ben Duguid noted that 60009 does.

[image: full 60009 from BrickLink]

Comment: The two parts you picked make totally good sense and prove your case.  Just to add: I don't think that garage door or the tiles over the windows are in very many sets either.

Comment: I ignored the tiles because you never know if they are printed or stickered, and I've found BrickLink inventories which have *some* stickers in the Counterparts section, but not *all* stickers.

And it just takes one designer who wants to bring back some old piece (like I read happened to the old lamp post) and suddenly it's in a dozen sets, so who knows if that will happen to the garage door pieces. They've been used in Friends sets as a shower door, if memory serves.

Comment: Its a MOD of 60009 i think.

Comment: As @mindstormsboi mentions, it looks like it's based very heavily on [Helicopter Arrest](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60009-1), which does indeed include the multi-coloured treasure chest.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I think it might just be Helicopter Arrest with the "pier" broken off, and none of the vehicles or minifigs.

Comment: @nick012000 it's had a small bird and light added as well ;)

Comment: As @mindstormsboi pointed out, it looks a **lot** like 60009. I fear if I delete this answer and re-answer, this related discussion will also disappear, so I'll just edit it.

Comment: I would like to explicitly express my appreciation of how my mistake was pointed out ever so politely and gently. Thanks!